# New File() - The operation is insecure

Tags: javascript

I've a problem with javascript. I'm making a AJAX based upload and have an array of all files uploaded. If the site is reloaded I want to restore all files to the array.

I do like this:

```
var file = new File({the url to the file on my server});
```

And I get:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

I use the same origin, and on my local server: mylocal:88/init.php?page=upload

```
var file = new File('http://mylocal:88/init.php?file=12345');
```

Gives me this error. Port, protocol and domain is the same.

Why and how to create a new file without getting this error?

Comment: Does it need to be `https`?

Comment: It's not https, I just removed the protocol in the post because it should not be a link.

Comment: I meant does the connection to your server need to be `https` to prevent the `SecurityError`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Javascript runs on client machines, they cannot allow client to create files on the server otherwise hacking into servers would be very easy.
The `FILE` object create file on the client side only.

```
EG: var file = new File("myfile.txt");

file.open("write,create", "text");
file.writeln("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs");
file.close();
```

You can however try jquery:

```
$.get('/init.php?file=12345', function(data) {//This function run when the request is completed.
      alert(data);
      console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! Never thought of that. Ofc it's only local files.